# Image analysis in R by using colocr

Tags: r

This is the first time for me to ask a question, hopefully I wrote my script in correct way.
I wanted to analyze my immunofluorescence images, each images have 2 different colors for same cells, and basically I want to show all the cells with blue stain which is stained by every cells, and pixel differences of green between images. I load the merged image which include blue and green stains. I used colocr package. However R doesn't recognize the blue stain, I confirm by looking images if all cells have blue. So I was wondering if anyone know what it is the solution to show blue stain.
I attached my script below

Thank you

```r
library(imager)
library(magick)
library(colocr)
library(imagerExtra)

image <- image_load(system.file('extdata', 'image.tif', package = 'colocr'))       # merge
    
image1 <- imager::channel(image, 1)  # blue
image2 <- imager::channel(image, 2)  # green
    
par(mfrow = c(1,3), mar = rep(1,4))
plot(image, axes = FALSE, main = 'Merged')
plot(image1, axes = FALSE, main = 'blue')
plot(image2, axes = FALSE, main = 'green')
```

Created on 2022-04-29 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

Comment: You're code isn't very well formatted, I can edit it for now, but for next time, see: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/979052) (the easier it is to read, the better answers you'll get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the index of the green and blue channels correct? Often channel 1 is red and channel 2 is green. To remove doubt, you could use `imager::G` to extract the green channel and `imager::B` to get the blue channel:

```r
library(imager)
library(magick)
library(colocr)
library(imagerExtra)

image <- image_load(system.file('extdata', 'example1.png', package = 'colocr'))
image1 <- B(image)  # blue
image2 <- G(image)  # green

par(mfrow = c(1,3), mar = rep(1,4))
plot(image, axes = FALSE, main = 'Merged')
plot(image1, axes = FALSE, main = 'blue')
plot(image2, axes = FALSE, main = 'green')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>